# Implementing MAA algorithm using Cryptol

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, pycrypto, cryptol

I tried to implement the MAA algorithm using Cryptol. Here is what I did so far, but I was not lucky. Any ideas?

```
main: ([32], [32]) -> [32]
main  (x , y)  =  add (x , y)x
           where x =  (take`{16} xy, drop`{16} xy)
          where xy = mul1 (x , y)      

mul1: ([32] ,[32])  -> [32]
mul1  (x , y) = xy
          where xy = x * y


add: ([16] ,[16])  -> [16]
add  (x , y) = xy
          where xy = x + y
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: `add` takes one tuple argument, not two arguments.  You are also shadowing the variable names, use unique names in `main`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main has a few mistakes.

- `add (x , y)x`  Say what?  Too many arguments
- `main  (x , y)  = ...` and `where x = ...`  Well what does x equal now?  Don't shadow variable names if you can help it.
- `where x = ...` and `where xy = ...`  Use a single `where instead of a nested just to keep things clean, eh?

Finally there is a type error.  Add gives you a 16 bit number (look at the type signature) so it's result can not also be the result of `main` who's type indicates it returns a 32 bit number.  32 does not equal 16.  I've fixed this, and the above, simply by changing the type of `main` but that likely isn't what you want, so you'll need to add whatever logic you desire here (ex: zero extend or sign extend?).

Code:

```
main: ([32], [32]) -> [16]
main  (x , y)  =  add xy16
           where xy16 =  (take`{16} xy, drop`{16} xy)
                 xy = mul1 (x , y)

mul1: ([32] ,[32])  -> [32]
mul1  (x , y) = xy
          where xy = x * y


add: ([16] ,[16])  -> [16]
add  (x , y) = xy
          where xy = x + y
```

Now presumably this is a cut down version of your original problem, but if not notice you really don't need to define a function `add` just to use `+` and same goes for `mul`.  Also you don't need the explicit type annotations on `take` and `drop` since those typed can be inferred.  For example:

```
main2 : [32] -> [32] -> [16]
main2 x y = take xy + drop xy where xy = x * y
```

And then we can do the obvious:

```
Main> :prove \x y -> main (x,y) == main2 x y
Q.E.D.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate that!